# Como reduzir formula .replace no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estou com um *dataframe* em que gostaria de substituir a codificação 0, 1 por sim e não. Algumas colunas do `df` possuem essa codificação e por isso escrevi o seguinte comando:

```
dados_trabalho = dados_trabalho.replace({"ASSINTOM": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"DOR ATIPICA": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"IAM": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"HAS": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"DM": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"DISPLIP": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"DOR TIPICA": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}})
```

Ele roda corretamente e substitui as colunas identificadas pela nova codificação, porém gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de resumir essa fórmula para que o *script* não fique enorme.

Tentei criar a função:

```
def change_columns(df):
    c = df.columns
    df = df.replace({c: {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}})
```

O problema é quando eu insiro o *dataframe* nesta função ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
change_columns(dados_trabalho)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-43eb9316b19b> in <module>
----> 1 change_columns(dados_trabalho)

<ipython-input-140-9fbbd4e9e293> in change_columns(df)
      1 def change_columns(df):
      2     c = df.columns
----> 3     df = df.replace({c: {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}})

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __hash__(self)
   2060 
   2061     def __hash__(self):
-> 2062         raise TypeError("unhashable type: %r" % type(self).__name__)
   2063 
   2064     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index'
```

Estou iniciando com Python e por isso acredito que esteja esquecendo alguma coisa.

RESOLVIDO:

Consegui resolver o problema com o seguinte codigo:

```
import pandas

def change_columns(df, cols):
    for col_name in cols:
        df = df.replace({col_name: {0:'sim', 1:'nao'}})
    return df

# create sample data
df = pandas.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
print('Starting DataFrame:')
print(df)

# define columns to do the replacement
columns_to_replace = [0, 2, 3]
# perform the replacement
df = change_columns(df, columns_to_replace)

# see the result
print('After processing DataFrame: ')
print(df)

Running the code above should produce the result:

Starting DataFrame:
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  1  0  1  1
1  1  0  1  0  1  0
After processing DataFrame:
     0  1   2    3  4  5
0  yes  0  no  yes  1  1
1   no  0  no  yes  1  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edição:** Reparei apenas depois de colocar a resposta, que já tinha solucionado o seu problema. Em qualquer caso, deixo aqui a resposta. Talvez possa ajudar alguém no futuro.

O seu problema resulta da forma como está a passar o parâmetro coluna à função replace. O nome da coluna é chave do dicionário e como tal deve ser de um tipo imutável. Devido a isto, não pode passar a lista com as colunas directamente.

Experimente fazer a seguinte alteração na sua função:

```
def change_columns(df):
    c = df.columns
    df.replace({c : {'0':'Sim', '1':'Nao'} for c in columns}, inplace=True)
```

A função anterior, é também equivalente a:

```
def change_columns(df):
    for c in df.columns:
        df.replace({c : {'0':'Sim', '1':'Nao'}}, inplace=True)
```

Note que é necessário filtrar as colunas onde deve ser aplicada a substituição, caso contrário, a substituição será efectuada em todas as colunas do DataFrame.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Bruno

Answer (score 2):

Bem, segundo a documentação do `pandas` você consegue fazer a substituição diretamente em todo o `DataFrame` da seguinte maneira (referência [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)):

```
df = df.replace(["Sim", "Não"], [1, 0])
```

Note que você está substituindo toda ocorrência dos valores "Sim" e "Não" por 0 e 1 respectivamente em todo o DataFrame, eliminando assim a necessidade de fazer um a um.

Comment: Igor obrigado pela resposta. O problema é que eu so quero aplicar nessas colunas. O df é maior e possui mais colunas. Quando rodo dessa maneira ele substitui em todas as colunas e nao nas que eu selecionei

Comment: Se você fizer `df[['coluna1', 'coluna2']].replace(["Sim", "Não"], [1, 0])` não resolve? Daí seleciona as colunas que você quer.